# Get only file name from find command and mail

Tags: unix, find, mailx

The following find command will results multiple files and send mail all those

```
find /home/cde -ctime -1 -name "Sum*pdf*" -exec uuencode {} {} \; |mailx -s "subject" abc@gmail.com
```

but I am getting attachments like "homecdeSum123.pdf" and "homecdeSum324.pdf". How to get exact file names in my attachment. Please help me on this

Comment: so the question is `Is it possible?`

Comment: yes, if possible i need a script for that

Comment: ok after you edit your question, it is now qualified to be voted as closed. you need at least show your codes, and tell us the problem you met.  Nobody will provide you a script here.

Comment: Hint for searching: `find` with the option `ctime -1` will get the files created today.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am able to find new file created but i am unable to pick up the file and mail it.so, how can i store the file/files that was/were generated and to be mailed.

Comment: As kent indicated above nobody will write your script for you, but to send a file from a unix server to an exchange server, you can use `uuencode file2attach attachment-name|sendmail user@domain.com` command. In addition to `find .....` command, using this method, you should be able to write your script pretty easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all attachments in single mail:

```
 find /home/cde -ctime -1 -name "Sum*pdf*" | while read name; do uuencode "$name" "${name##*/}"; done | mailx -s "subject" abc@example.com
```

to get separate mail:

```
find /home/cde -ctime -1 -name "Sum*pdf*" | while read name; do uuencode "$name" "${name##*/}"| mailx -s "subject" abc@example.com ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer what seems to be at least part of your question

> but I am getting attachments like "homecdeSum123.pdf" and "homecdeSum324.pdf". How to get exact file names in my attachment.

The accepted answer to this question: 
[find: What's up with basename and dirname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428628/find-whats-up-with-basename-and-dirname)
contains a lot of useful information in my opinion, but I am trying to extract what could be the answer to the above:

What you describe is that when you are doing

```
find /home/cde ....
```

you are getting file names like "homecdeSum123.pdf" so my take is that you only want the basename of the file, not also the directory.

This can be accessed like this (as an example only listing)

```
find `pwd` -name "*.png" -exec echo $(basename {} ) \;
```

A slight variation of this is to use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` which is (taking from the man page):

> -execdir command {} +
>
> ```
>          Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started find.
> ```

Does this help?

Comment: @ Erik, Thank you. I can -exec basename but after that i couldn't send those files as attachments. in find command the resulting files are co ming with path name i want only the exact file name in attachment

Comment: @Aravind what I showed can also be combined with what you wrote e.g. by using `-exec uuencode $(basename {}) $(basename {}) ';'` but maybe I am missing your point again?

Comment: @ Erik I have used `-exec uuencode $(basename {}) $(basename {}) \;| mailx -s "North" abc@gmail` but still i am getting attachments including path.