# how to pass "one" argument and use it twice in "xargs" command

Tags: bash, shell, echo, popen, xargs

I tried to use the `xargs` to pass the arguments to the `echo`:

```
[usr@linux scripts]$ echo {0..4} | xargs -n 1 echo
0
1
2
3
4
```

the `-n 1` insured that the `xargs` pass `1` arguments a time to the `echo`.

Then I want to use this aruments twice, however the results is not I wanted:

```
[usr@linux scripts]$ echo {0..4} | xargs -I@ -n 1 echo @,@
0 1 2 3 4,0 1 2 3 4
```

the `-n 1` seems disabled when I added the `-I@`, 
and this is the result I wanted:

```
0,0
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
```

how can I achieve that?

--------Supply------------------
I have used the method recommanded by @123 ,however ,there are still another question:

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
a[0]=1
a[1]=2
echo "a[0] and a[1] : "${a[0]}, ${a[1]}
echo -n {0..1} | xargs -I num -d" " echo num,${a[num]},num
```

and this is the output:

```
[usr@linux scripts]$ sh test.sh 
a[0] and a[1] : 1, 2
0,1,0
1,1,1
```

you can see that the array `a` is not returned the value I wanted :<
And How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `echo -n {0..4} | xargs -I@ -d' ' echo @,@` ? `printf "%s\n" {0..4} | xargs -I@ echo @,@` ?

Comment: could you have a look at this question I just updated? There still some questions when using the arguments :(@123

Comment: Shell expansion occurs before xargs ever see it, so it is always evaluated as `${a[num]}` aka `${a[0]}`. could do something silly like `xargs -I num -d" " bash -c 'echo $num' "${a[@]}"` but theres probably a better way of achieving whatever your end goal is.

Comment: @123 I just have some doubts about  `bash -c 'echo $num' "${a[@]}"`, how about the first `echo $num` works? It's seems to be the `$num` is substituted the `@` in the `${a[@]}`?

Comment: And I just tried a command like this `a[0]=x;a[1]=y;num=1;bash -c 'echo $num' "{a[@]}"`, the output I expected is y, however the output is just blank.

Comment: There is no `$` before `{a[@]}`...

Comment: this is a mistake about typing, I used the command with the `$`, it's just doesn't work, does it works in your computer?

Comment: No, it's a completely different command than what i provided though, num is not being evaluated in the new shell as it hasn't been exported, xargs is substituting it in the previous example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126093/discussion-between-spring-cc-and-123).

Answer (score 17):

If you can't change the input format, you could set the delimiter to a space:

```
$ echo -n {0..4} | xargs -d " " -I@ echo @,@
0,0
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
```

Otherwise, change the input to separate the tokens with a newline:

```
$ printf "%s\n" {0..4} | xargs -I@ echo @,@
0,0
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
```

The reason for this syntax is explained in `man xargs`

```
-I replace-str

Replace occurrences of replace-str in the  initial-arguments  with  names  read  from
standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the sep‐
arator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

So you must set the delimiter manually to a space if you want to delimit fields.

Comment: @123: I am not entirely sure why OP's version doesn't work. Apparently `xargs` splits the input line on whitespace when the `-I` option is not used, but with `-I` it treats the line as one argument. I couldn't find a good explanation of this in the man page...

Comment: Under `-I` > `Also, unquoted blanks do
              not terminate input items; instead the separator is the
              newline character.`

Comment: Could you have a look a the question which I just updated? There are still some question in using of the arguments :(

Comment: @springcc: re the edit, the reason why it doesn't work is that the variables are substituted before xargs is executed, so `${a[num]}` gets the first value of array, since `var` is undefined. You could solve it using eval, but there is probably a better solution...

Comment: @user000001 I have tried the eval as `eval echo -n {0..1} | xargs -I num -d" " echo num,${a[num]},num`, however it still not work. Do you have some method?

Comment: @springcc You have encountered a long-known problem.
You can't use `xagrs -I` replacement as array iterator. So you need to invoke some subshell via `eval`, or just using `bash -c`. So you will need to export your array, but... You can't export an array in bash :) From manpage:
`Array variables may not (yet) be exported.`

In fact, there are some hacks do to that, but better way is to adjust the logic of your script and give only usual variables to xargs.

Comment: Using null separation `\0` in `printf` also works if you pass `-0` to `xargs`, like this: `printf "%s\0" {0..4} | xargs -0 -I{} -n 1 echo "{},{}"`.

Comment: See also here: [Why using dirname in find command gives dots for each match?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158279/4561887). In some cases, using `bash -c` ensures you get the proper substitution.